# How to display HTML content from API response on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I sent a fetch request to an API which responded with:

```html
<Game Gameid="12345">
    <name primary="true">Apple</name>           
    <year>2011</year>
</Game>
```

Just wondering how I would display this data on my HTML page. I'm assuming I would need to process this with javascript or something.

Here is my current javascript:

```js
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Just want the name and year displayed in a Div or something

Comment: Yes, you should process that. Just response does not contain JSON, but XML

Comment: api response data is json or text?

Comment: response is XML i believe

Answer (score -1):

Here is a small script demonstrating how to extract data from an XML string:

```js
const xml=`<Game Gameid="12345">
    <name primary="true">Apple</name>           
    <year>2011</year>
</Game>`;

const dom=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
const game=dom.querySelector("*");
// console.log(game.tagName,game.getAttribute("Gameid"));
const data = [...game.children].reduce((a,t)=>(a[t.tagName]=t.textContent,a), {});

document.querySelector("div").textContent=`The name is ${data.name} and the year is ${data.year}.`;
```

```html
<div></div>
```